# How to get Parameters of web Page with multipart, using commons.fileupload

Tags: jsp, servlets, apache-commons

Can anybody help me access **request.getParameter()** using **encryption type multipart**. Or please tell me if there is any other way **to get Parameters of the web page, with multipart**?

Answer (score 0):

You get parameters in the same way as you would normally. I mean, that within the doPost() method you call getParameter("paramtername") on the request object.

For example:

If your form to upload is as follows:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/servletupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" value="testvalue" name ="parametername"/>
    Select file: <input type="file" name="file" size="60"/>
    <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

your doPost() method would as follows:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String parametername = request.getParameter("parametername");

    // upload code here

}
```

Comment: That's what I was asking. I am unable to get parameters normally using enc-type as multipart. I am getting Null Value.
Parameter Name:null
Action: null
Data Base Name: null


This is the Result.